# How to change certain part of alert message color and font in Java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to change certain part of text to `bold` and `red color`.

It's not working on Microsoft Edge.

**My code:**

```
alert("Hi how are you my friend");
```

**Need to make text :** `"friend"` as `bold` and `red color`

**I tried this but does not work**

```
alert("Hi how are you my <b> <background-color = red"> friend </b>);
```

Any solution is much appreciated

Comment: @Tom : No tom without any package installation I want it

Comment: I don't think it is possible using `alert()`. You either have to create your own alert with html and css or use a library.

Comment: `window.alert()` only allows strings of text, not styled content. See [alert documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert). Creating a message box with HTML/CSS does not need a package if you style it yourself - but you will have to code a little.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible i searched for this problem a lot, but you can make your window ,it isn't hard to find tutorials.

> e.g  https://www.delftstack.com/howto/javascript/javascript-customize-alert-box/

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use the dialog tag in jQuery to create the alert,it somehow has been styled in the jQuery theme already.... Styling JavaScript alert box on my end here I don't think it's possible